# Check database table for already existing numbers?

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

I am using the following code to insert a random number into my table in SQL. Is there a way I can check the column first to make sure that the number being inserted does not already exist and if so regenerate it?

```
Dim random As String = DateTime.Now.ToString("ffssffff").Replace("PM", String.Empty).Replace("AM", String.Empty)
```

Comment: And how are you inserting?

Comment: I have an insert statement in vb "','" & random & "')"

Comment: by executing an `SQL Command` in your code?

Comment: Are you sure this is what you want to do? If you just need a unique value in your database, you can use a GUID, created either in your code with `Guid.NewGuid()`, or in SQL using `newid()`. This will guarantee uniqueness, and will be "random enough" - at least more random than pulling the fractions of a second from the current time. (Just so there's no argument here, GUID's aren't guaranteed to be random - the current implementation is based on a randomizer, but future implementations are not guaranteed to be, and past implementations were not - but they are guaranteed to be unique).

Comment: yes  Try
                Dim Con As SqlConnection
                Dim cmd As SqlCommand
                Con = New SqlConnection
                Con.ConnectionString = ""
                Con.Open()

                cmd = New SqlCommand
                cmd.Connection = Con
                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO   etc

Comment: Do I just do Guid.NewGuid() or is there more code to generate this

Comment: `Guid.NewGuid()` will generate an object of type `Guid`. It's a 128-bit number, generally displayed as 32 hex values (`01234567-89ab-cdef-0123-456789abcdef`). There are various overloads of `ToString()` which allow you to display it different ways. SQL Server has a `uniqueidentifier` data type which matches the `Guid` data type, or you can simply `ToString("N")`, which will give you the 32 characters, and you can store it in a `char(32)` field.

Comment: Can I create a GUID with just numbers and 6 characters?

Comment: Then the insert `If Not Exists(select * from tablename where code='1448523')` from the link that Marek Šíp provided is your best choise. And in addition to what Joe Enos said, you can always make that column an `Identity` to auto increment.

Comment: Unfortunately, no - GUIDs are designed to be unique as a whole, so there's no guarantee that a part of a GUID is unique. You can use a traditional random number generator to give you a random string, but 6 characters really isn't enough to even be reasonably sure you won't run into duplicates, so you'd still have to check to see if it exists before trying to insert.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to read this: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/162627/how-to-insert-new-record-in-my-table-if-not-exists

Comment: If I do this insert into tablename (code)
 Select '1448523' Where not exists(select * from tablename where code='1448523')
How do I then regenerate the number if it exists?

Comment: That would be question for someone else, I'm not VB programmer, I think you can use TRY, see this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk6t46tz.aspx

Comment: Have you tried to reference it back to where the code generates?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do this. Either from the code or from the Sql Query.

If you are generating random number from your code then you have to retrieve the data to check if there is already same number present in Database like

```
int noOfRow = IsValuePresentInDB("myValue"); // this function retrieve the specified record from Database.
if(noOfRow >0)
{
  // Regenerate it
}
else
{
  // insert it
}
```

From Sql Query you can use `IF EXIST` clause to check the existing record. But this approach will not useful if you are generating random number from Code.